# Warning message not working on openerp

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

I want to show a warning message in user interface side in my module in a particular condition.For that I have write the code like this.

```
raise osv.except_osv(('Warning!'), ("Entered Quantity is greater than quantity on source."))
```

But in that condition in user interface side it just showing the loading image.

At the console I got the error like this.

```
2013-06-10 09:45:53,612 364
ERROR None openerp.netsvc: Warning! Entered Quantity is greater than quantity on source.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\netsvc.py", line 361, in dispatch_rpc
     result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 585, in dispatch
     res = fn(db, uid, *params)
   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 167, in execute_kw
     return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 121, in wrapper
     return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 176, in execute
     res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-server\openerp\osv\osv.py", line 164, in execute_cr
     return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
   File "C:\OpenErp\openerp\openobject-addons\mat_mgmt\mat_mgmt.py", line 101, in button_confirm
     raise osv.except_osv(('Warning!'), ("Entered Quantity is greater than quantity on source."))
except_osv:
  ('Warning!', 'Entered Quantity is greater than quantity on source.')
c:\openerp\openerp\openobject-addons\mat_mgmt\mat_mgmt.py(101)button_confirm()
-> raise osv.except_osv(('Warning!'), ("Entered Quantity is greater than quantity on source."))
```

I want to show the warning message on user interface side.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to import

```
from openerp.tools.translate import _
```

then, you can get the job done!

```
raise osv.except_osv(_(u'TitleMessage'), _(u'BodyMessage'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display a warning message, you might look at using the `action_warn` client action. You invoke it by returning a dictionary like this one from your server action:

```
{
    'type': 'ir.actions.client',
    'tag': 'action_warn',
    'name': 'Warning',
    'params': {
       'title': 'Warning!',
       'text': 'Entered Quantity is greater than quantity on source.',
       'sticky': True
    }
}
```

This may be more genteel than you're looking for, though, if you want something that will actually stop a form submission. It displays a Growl-like notification in the user's browser. But if all you want to do is give the user some feedback in the form of a notification, either this or `action_info` (invoked the same way as `action_warn`) should do nicely.

I've got a fuller example [up on my blog](http://ryepdx.com/2014/12/message-boxes-in-openerpodoo/), but hopefully this is enough to get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same probleme and I resolved by :

```
from odoo import models, fields, api, _, osv # here add osv

raise osv.osv.except_osv(('Warning!'), ("Entered Quantity is greater than quantity on source.")) # here replace osv by osv.osv
```

I did this b-coz you will find the finction in odoo/osv/osv.py file

Answer (score -1):

Can you check with below code

```
raise osv.except_osv('Warning!', "Entered Quantity is greater than quantity on source.")
```

If you need translated messages then try _('meesage....')

But do not miss to import statement

`from openerp.tools.translate import _`

Comment: do not use (), try _() or just  "message..."

Comment: this is not totally about () or _() issue, i did this in all way you said, but no luck..