# Odoo - raise javascript warning

Tags: javascript, python, odoo

How to raise a javascript warning in Odoo?

There is an example in /addons/web_view_editor/static/src/js/view_editor.js:

```
this.do_warn(_t("The following fields are invalid :"), msg)
```

How to call similar function by `on_change` method, for instance, in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017215/warning-message-not-working-on-openerp#answer-27701172) in a similar question refers you can `return`:

```
{
'type': 'ir.actions.client',
'tag': 'action_warn',
'name': 'Warning',
'params': {
   'title': 'Warning!',
   'text': 'Entered Quantity is greater than quantity on source.',
   'sticky': True
}
}
```

To display messages like ODOO do. I hope this can be helpful for you.

Comment: That´s precisely it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Onchange methods can return a dictionary with a standard structure that will be interpreted by the web client.
[Here you can read the return format, in particular:](https://www.odoo.com/forum/how-to/developers-13/what-should-onchange-methods-do-and-return-57760)

> Onchange methods can show errors and/or change fields domain/values by returning a dictionary with one of more of these keys:
>
> `warning`
>          Used to show an error popup, useful for example for alerting the user that the value he inserted is invalid.
>           The value should be a dict in the form {'title': , 'message': } where  will be the title of the error popup and  the error message.
>   [...]

So you can raise a warning dialog by returning, for example:

```
return {
    'warning': {
        'title': 'Invalid value',
        'message': 'The field percentage must be an integer between 0 and 100'
    }
}
```

You cannot call and execute arbitrary javascript functions from the onchange method (which is backend python code), you can only interact with the webclient using the return dictionary.

Comment: Hey, i actually know about `warning`, however I thought it is possible to call a javascript warning  similar to that which comes when a required field is not filled. Thanks anyway

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot, at least without changing/inheriting the odoo code that handles the onchange return value, which is possible but I wouldn't recommend it.